# Getting the current index within the ForEach

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Channels and some of my channels have unassigned units which are then passed into a separate container. What i really want to do is to have the index of the current position of my list within the ForEach call to be passed in my container. Can I do something like this with linq or am i better off using a for..loop instead?

Would love to use linq if possible :)
Anyway here's my code:

```
item.Channels.Where(ch => !ch.IsSkipped).ForEach(
                    ch =>
                        {
                            if (ch.AssignedUnit == null)
                            {
                                //unknownUnitChannels.Add(ch);
                                unknownUnitChannels.Add(index, ch) <== This is the index i'd like to pass there
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Which `ForEach` method is this? There isn't one on `IEnumerable<T>` normally... Additionally, are you interested in the index *before* filtering or *after* filtering? For example, if the first 10 items are filtered out due to the `Where` clause, would you expect `index` to be 0 or 10?

Comment: Or you could spare yourself some effort, and do unknownUnitChannels.AddRange(item.Channels.Where(ch => !ch.IsSkipped && ch.AssignedUnit == null))

Comment: Before filtering if possible. The ForEach is a custom extension used in the project. I might as well use the c# foreach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the original index (before `Where` is applied), you need something like:

```
item.Channels.Select((c, i) => new { Channel = c, Index = i })
             .Where(x => !x.Channel.IsSkipped)
             .ForEach(x =>
             /* x.Channel is your item, x.Index is its original Index */
             );
```

Comment: that looks nice. I like the fact I can do Select((c, i) => new { Channel = c, Index = i } before Where

Answer (score 3):

Anything that is being `ForEach`'d doesn't necessarily have an index. Not every `IEnumerable` is stored by index.

If you want to have an index, you can do something like this:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var ch in item.Channels.Where(x => x.IsSkipped))
{     
    if (ch.AssignedUnit == null) {
        unknownUnitChannels.Add(index, ch);
    }
    index++;
}
```

if you want the index before filtering, do this:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var ch in item.Channels)
{     
    if (ch.AssignedUnit == null && !x.IsSkipped) {
        unknownUnitChannels.Add(index, ch);
    }
    index++;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't use the index before filtering, but a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: see my edit for a way to do it with the index before filtering.